# String constructor

Tags: c#, string, constructor

We can say,

```
string myString = "Hello";
```

Which 'magically' constructs a new string object holding that value.

Why can't a similar 'construction-less' approach be used for objects created from classes we define in our code? What's the 'magic' that VS does for `string`s? And for `enum`s?

I've never seen an explanation of how this works.

Comment: You should read about implicit and explicit constructors

Comment: Magic that VS does? You know VS is a glorified text editor, and that it's actually your compiler doing the "magic"?

Comment: [This is what actually happens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111194/does-ldstr-internally-implement-newobj) behind the magic, incidentally.

Answer (score 25):

Basically, it's part of the C# language specification: there's syntax for string literals, numeric literals, character literals and Boolean literals, but that's all.

The compiler uses these literals to generate IL, and for *most* of them, there's a suitable instruction for "constant of a particular type", so it's directly represented. One exception to this is `decimal`, which is *not* a primitive type in terms of the CLR, and so has to have extra support. (That's why you can't specify a `decimal` argument when applying an attribute, for example.)

The simplest way to see what happens is to use ildasm (or a similar tool) to look at the IL generated for any specific bit of source code.

In terms of creating your own classes - you *could* provide an implicit conversion from `string` (or something else) to your own type, but that wouldn't have quite the same effect. You could write source code of:

```
MyType x = "hello";
```

... but that wouldn't be a "constant" of type `MyType`... it would just be an initializer which happened to use your implicit conversion.

Comment: I was of the idea that you can define and implicit constructor in your complex types to achieve the same effect, like in this question example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815695/whats-the-reason-of-using-implicit-explicit-convertions-instead-of-constructors

Comment: @Tallmaris: I was just editing to mention this - you can't define an implicit *constructor*, but you can define an implicit *conversion*. It's not quite the same thing though.

Comment: Yes, poor choice of word but that's what I meant :) Also, it's not the same effect, as you pointed out in your edit.

Answer (score 7):

In fact, you can do so for your custom classes. It's achieved by defining your own implicit conversions from other types. It's covered very well in msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288476%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Here's a example modified for string:

```
class Email
{
    private string user;
    private string domain;

    public Email(string user, string domain)
    {
        this.user = user;
        this.domain = domain;
    }

    static public implicit operator Email(string value) // magic goes here ;)
    {
        var parts = value.Split('@');
        if (parts.Length != 2)
            return null;

        return new Email(parts[0], parts[1]);
    }

    static public implicit operator string(Email value)
    {
        return "{ User = " + value.user + ", Domain = " + value.domain + " }";
    }
}

class Test
{
    static public void Main()
    {
        Email test = "alice@test.com"

        System.Console.WriteLine("Test: " + test);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The C# compiler turns this into the corresponding CIL instruction: `ldstr`. There is no equivalent for your own complex type, so the compiler must emit a `newobj` CIL instruction, which calls the constructor of your type. The syntax you suggest would hide this constructor call from the user.

Comment: On top there is no new ;) The string already exists in the constants table as it is created during type load (for this particular case) and is... interned.

Comment: Well, it can be interned, but it is not as the C# compiler applies [CompilationRelaxationsAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/30c1sk6h(v=vs.110).aspx) with [CompilationRelaxations.NoStringInterning](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.compilationrelaxations(v=vs.110).aspx) by default. Of course if you use the same string twice  in the same assembly it refers to the same string, though.

Comment: Actually it does. In the above example the string is a constant and constants are interned by the linker ;)

Comment: They are not interned in the traditional CLR sense, but yes, two identical hardcoded strinngs will refer to the same string (in the same assembly).

Answer (score 1):

Although the actual mechanics differ slightly from what I'll describe here, it's important to realize a string is not created when the code `string myString = "Hello";` is *executed*.  Rather, the string is created when the code is *loaded*.

The code for each assembly contains a big blob of binary data data is read into an array along with the code.  If the code contains 23 different string literals, then the contents of all those literals will appear in the array along with 23 entries, each of which lists the starting index and length one of the strings.  The process is conceptually similar to:

```
char[] RawData;  // Gets loaded by the runtime
string [] StringLiterals;

void create_strings()
{
  int numStrings = (int)RawData[0] + 65536*(int)RawData[1];
  StringLiterals= new string[numStrings];
  for (int i=0; i<numStrings; i++)
  {
    int header = i*4+2;
    int startLoc = (int)RawData[header] + 65536*(int)RawData[header+1];
    int length  = (int)RawData[header+2] + 65536*(int)RawData[header+3];
    StringsLiterals[i] = new String(RawData, startOfs, length);
  }
}
```

If "Hello" happens to be the 7th string defined in an assembly, then the characters "Hello" would appear in the RawData at the position defined by entry #7.  The aforementioned statement would then be translated as `string myString = StringLiterals[7];`--not creating a new object, but simply returning a reference to an object which was created when the class was loaded.